# Remove Duplicate Lines completely

Tags: vb.net, duplicates, removeall

I have searched the internet everywhere rn

I just need a code that removed ALL my duplicated in my string / list / richtextbox
Heres an example what i want:

**I ACCEPT C# & VB.NET CODE**

From:

```
asd
asd
djsdjjd
252
```

to:

```
djsdjjd
252
```

Codes i've tried:

```vb
Dim liness As New List(Of String)(RichTextBox1.Lines)
Dim lines2() As String = (From s As String In liness).Distinct.ToArray
RichTextBox1.Lines = lines2
Dim count As Integer = liness.Count - lines2.Length
MessageBox.Show(count.ToString)
```

&

```vb
Dim lines1 As New List(Of String)(RichTextBox1.Lines)
Dim testint As Integer
For i As Integer = lines1.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
    If lines1(i) = lines1(i - 1) Then
        lines1.RemoveAt(i)
        lines1.RemoveAt(i - 1)
        i = -1
    End If
Next
MsgBox("")
RichTextBox1.Lines = lines1.ToArray
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can also use:

```
Dim newLines() As String = liness.Where(Function(s) liness.Where(Function(s1) s = s1).Count = 1).ToArray
```

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways this could be done. Here is just one of them:

```vb
Dim linesByCount As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

For Each line In RichTextBox1.Lines
    If linesByCount.ContainsKey(line) Then
        lineByCount(line) += 1
    Else
        lineByCount.Add(line, 1)
    End If
Next

Dim uniqueLines As New List(Of String)

For Each line In linesByCount.Keys
    If linesByCount(line) = 1 Then
        uniqueLines.Add(line)
    End If
Next

RichTextBox1.Lines = lines.ToArray()
```

Here's another option using LINQ:

```vb
RichTextBox1.Lines = RichTextBox1.Lines.
                                  GroupBy(Function(s) s).
                                  Where(Function(g) g.Count() = 1).
                                  Select(Function(g) g.Key).
                                  ToArray()
```

Whichever option you choose, the trick is to get the count of each value first, before removing anything. Otherwise, you won't know that the last instance of a duplicate is actually a duplicate. That said, neither of these options actually remove anything. They create a list with a count of each item and then they pick out the items with a count of 1 and add them to a new list.

Here's yet another option:

```vb
Dim lines = RichTextBox1.Lines

RichTextBox1.Lines = lines.Where(Function(s) Array.IndexOf(lines, s) = Array.LastIndexOf(lines, s)).ToArray()
```